# Type '(props: Props) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<FieldRenderProps<any, HTMLElement>>' with React-final-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-final-form

I'm beginner to typescript and I'm trying to create a signUp form using `React-Final-Form` and `Typescript`. So I create my form which is described by:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import PasswordField from "../../components/Password";
import TextField from "../../components/TextField";
import { validate, submit } from "./validation";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    container: {
      padding: 16,
      margin: "auto",
      maxWidth: 600
    },
    paper: {
      padding: 16
    },
    item: {
      marginTop: 16
    }
  })
);

const SignUp = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Typography>SignUp Form</Typography>
      <Form
        onSubmit={submit}
        validate={validate}
        render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <Grid container alignItems='flex-start' spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Field
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    name='Username'
                    component={TextField}
                    type='text'
                    label='Username'
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Field
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    name='Email'
                    component={TextField}
                    type='text'
                    label='Email'
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Field
                    fullWidth
                    required
                    name='Password'
                    component={PasswordField}
                    type='password'
                    label='Password'
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.item}>
                  <Button
                    type='button'
                    variant='contained'
                    onClick={form.reset}
                    disabled={submitting || pristine}
                  >
                    Reset
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.item}>
                  <Button
                    variant='contained'
                    color='primary'
                    type='submit'
                    disabled={submitting}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Paper>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

Which needs the componet `TextField` and `Password`:

TextField.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    textField: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  })
);

interface Props {
  label: string;
  value: string;
  handleChange: () => {};
  type: string;
}

const SimpleTextField = (props: Props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { label, value, handleChange, type } = props;

  return (
    <TextField
      id='outlined-name'
      label={label}
      className={classes.textField}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      type={type}
      margin='normal'
      variant='outlined'
    />
  );
};

export default SimpleTextField;
```

However tslint returns this error:

```
Type '(props: Props) => Element' is not assignable to type '"textarea" | "input" | "select" | ComponentClass<FieldRenderProps<any, HTMLElement>, any> | FunctionComponent<FieldRenderProps<any, HTMLElement>> | undefined'.
  Type '(props: Props) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<FieldRenderProps<any, HTMLElement>>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'FieldRenderProps<any, HTMLElement> & { children?: ReactNode; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': label, value, handleChange, type  TS2322

    44 |                     required
    45 |                     name='Username'
  > 46 |                     component={TextField}
       |                     ^
    47 |                     type='text'
    48 |                     label='Username'
    49 |                   />
```

I tried to change the return of `TextField` by modifing the code like that:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    textField: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  })
);

interface Props {
  label: string;
  value: string;
  handleChange: () => {};
  type: string;
}

const SimpleTextField = (props: Props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { label, value, handleChange, type } = props;

  return (
    <TextField
      id='outlined-name'
      label={label}
      className={classes.textField}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      type={type}
      margin='normal'
      variant='outlined'
    />
  );
};

const TextFieldWrapper = (props: Props) => {
   return(
     <>
      <SimpleTextField {...props}/>
     </>
   )
}

export default TextFieldWrapper;
```

But still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import PasswordField from "../../components/Password";
import TextField from "../../components/TextField";
import { validate, submit } from "./validation";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    container: {
      padding: 16,
      margin: "auto",
      maxWidth: 600
    },
    paper: {
      padding: 16
    },
    item: {
      marginTop: 16
    }
  })
);

const SignUp = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Typography>SignUp Form</Typography>
      <Form
        onSubmit={submit}
        validate={validate}
        render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <Grid container alignItems='flex-start' spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Field fullWidth required name='Username'>
                    {props => (
                      <TextField
                        label='Username'
                        type='text'
                        value={props.input.value}
                        onChange={props.input.onChange}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Field>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Field fullWidth required name='Email'>
                    {props => (
                      <TextField
                        label='Email'
                        type='email'
                        value={props.input.value}
                        onChange={props.input.onChange}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Field>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Field fullWidth required name='Password'>
                    {props => (
                      <PasswordField
                        label='Password'
                        type='password'
                        value={props.input.value}
                        onChange={props.input.onChange}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Field>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.item}>
                  <Button
                    type='button'
                    variant='contained'
                    onClick={form.reset}
                    disabled={submitting || pristine}
                  >
                    Reset
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.item}>
                  <Button
                    variant='contained'
                    color='primary'
                    type='submit'
                    disabled={submitting}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Paper>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

Comment: what was the change u did?

Answer (score 0):

```
'FieldRenderProps<any, HTMLElement> & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

does not have the fields you defined in props. Will the parent component pass the props you defined to your component?

Comment: I tried to follow this section [component](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps#fieldrenderprops) described into the documentation.

Comment: I think your component should accept props of this type https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldRenderProps